# Is it possible to combine a regex url pattern with url converter

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I have two different paths in django-project urls

```
re_path(internal_site_url, internal_site), #for internal sites #internal_site_url is re_pattern
path('<path:site_url>', external_site) #for external sites
```

but re_path in first path would not include path converter path:site_url for further usage in a view, in comparison with the second one.
So how could I achive combining re-pattern match with path conversion?

Answer (score 1):

[The Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/urls/) show how to capture parts of a URL in a `re_path` for use in a view:

```py
re_path(r'^bio/(?P<username>\w+)/$', views.bio, name='bio'),
```

In this example, the keyword variable `username` will be available in the view.

Comment: So how should an code look according to an example provided in question, let's pretend that the re pattern for an internal site is "localhost:"?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [contributor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12735064/schwartz721) and to [django url tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/urls/), the answer is

```
re_path(r'(?P<site_url>{})'.format(internal_site_url), internal_site), #for internal sites #internal_site_url is re_pattern
path('<path:site_url>', external_site) #for external sites
```